# ImageMagick - convert multi-page PDF to TIFF results in 3 identical images per TIFF Page

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a multi-page PDF.

When I use ImageMagick to convert it to TIFF, the resulting TIFF repeats each PDF page three times.

I've experimented with ImageMagick options. The basic command is:

```
convert input.pdf output.tiff
```

Files are [here](https://gofile.io/d/imbpnZ).

Comment: Can reproduce, but I'm getting warnings by ImageMagick related to the number of channels. Do you just want to save the images as TIFF? `pdfimages input.pdf -tiff output` could do that.

Comment: I can repeat that with your PDF. I suggest you post a bug report to the Imagemagick GIT forum

Comment: Thanks both. My use case is I need to convert PDFs to TIFF to extract OCR with Tesseract. I will post on the Git forum but any other suggestions to meet my use case are welcome. Looking into pdfimages now...